# Two Sample Discrete K-S Test

Tags: probability, discrete-data, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Recently I got a review for a paper that asked me to show that two probability distributions match. They hinted that I should perform Two Sample K-S test. I know there is a discrete R package dgof to do that. But I have few questions.

Let, we have two discrete disributions $P$ and $Q$, where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ denotes the discrete probability with $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

1. **Missing values:** There are many missing probaility values in $P$ and $Q$. For example, $P$ has $15,083$ non-zero probabilities where maximum value of $x$ is $1,959,427$. On the other hand $Q$ has $15,105$ non-zero probabilities with maximum $x=1,959,014$. Thereore, fo some value of $x$ the probability is non-zero in $P$ but empty in $Q$. How do I treat this? Should I take only the values which are both non-zero in $P$ and $Q$. (Currently, while calculating the cdf, I am treating the missing probabilities as $0$)
2. **Power-Law:** I know that both values come from some variation of power-law degree distribution. Should I apply any extra operations?
3. I can compute the $D$ values using wikipedia. But how do I compute the p-value?

Comment: "to show that two probability distributions match" -- a goodness of fit test won't show that --  a failure to reject doesn't mean the null is true, it means your sample size was too small.

Comment: Can you suggest what should I use? I can take many such distributions and take average to show that all those belong to the same class. Will it work? I also tried KL divergence.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You cannot show that samples from two distributions are the same or even from the same family